# How do I use a Python Twitch IRC Bot to take chat message parameters?

Tags: python, sockets, irc, twitch

I am fairly new to Python coding and was just wondering if anybody knew of an easy way for my Python Twitch IRC Bot using sockets can receive and handle message command parameters. For example, if I were to set up song requests, and a user in the chat types in "!songrequest URL," how would I be able to recognize the URL and process it? (I already have a method of retrieving the YouTube video title from the link, by the way). In simplest form, what I'm looking for is to take arguments from a chat message command and put it into a separate variable.
If it helps, here is how I retrieve commands from the Twitch chat:

```
s = openSocket()

if "!command" in message:

sendMessage(s, "Message")
break
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, you're trying to extract the url in your user's chat message? (per your example)

Comment: See if my answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently built a whatsapp bot with a similar feature; essentially, you can do it like this using `split()`:

```
if message.startswith(command):
    your_function(message.split(' ')[1])
```

Where `command` is the string version of your command, obviously (i.e. '!songrequest`)

This splits the string by whitspace, so that it returns URL if the message reads: "!songrequest URL".

Note that `str.split()` returns a list by default, and since you want the second element of the split you'll have to pass the index (`[1]`) to get that element.

The reason I'd go with `message.startswith()` is that this way the bot doesn't trigger when you tell people about the `!songrequest` command somewhere in your own sent messages (i.e.""You can use !songrequest to request a song!").